# what does ‘mc’ mean in the word 'mcmodel=medium'?

Tags: c, gcc

**The question is as the title.Is that an abbreviation?**
I have tried to search on google but can't find answer easily.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: gcc's error information.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049389/gcc-error-when-compiling-that-already-has-answers)

Comment: Taking a wild guess, memory consumption model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html),

> These ‘-m’ switches are supported in addition to the above on x86-64 processors in 64-bit environments.

So `-m` indicates a machine-specific option. And then

> -mcmodel=medium
>
> Generate code for the medium model: the program is linked in the lower 2 GB of the address space. Small symbols are also placed there. Symbols with sizes larger than -mlarge-data-threshold are put into large data or BSS sections and can be located above 2GB. Programs can be statically or dynamically linked.

So `cmodel` stands for "code model" which decides maximum limits concerning how the program is linked together. "Medium" is in fact big enough to accommodate programs with global objects greater than 2 GB, which is gigantic by most standards.